# How to track the area within a rubberband rectangle in a video as it streams using C#

Tags: c#, webcam, tracking

I am doing a project in C# called User Initiated Real Time Object Tracking. What I want is, take input from a webcamera to a picturebox(done using dshownet), then draw a rubber band rectangle on the video(say on a person's face/eye/nose/whole body - i think i am going to scope it down to face) using a mouse, then I want to track the area enclosed by the rubber band rectangle.

I am currently going through dshownet bitmapmixer sample in the samples folder to learn how to draw on a video(no success yet, however, i have done the rubberband rectangle, its now a matter of making it work on top of the video).

[image]

My main issue is to track, what is enclosed within the rubber band rectangle(after the rectangle is drawn it stays visible, unless erased with a button command). Someone said to go through [Face and eyes Detection](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23191/Face-and-Eyes-Detection-Using-OpenCV)(I dont do detection in my project really). Well, I might be wrong.

The way I think of it is as this, I think if I could consider the area outside the rectangle as the background, and the extract the colour histograms of the area within the  rectangle(foreground) and check if it pops up in the subsequent frames, I can successfully track[I actually dont know how to achieve this via code]. Is this correct ??

By the way, I consider the tracker to be the rectangle, which will stay visible as long as the video is streaming and move along with the person in the video. To start off, I am experimenting all this with a saved video file.

Any ideas on how to do the tracking ? Does it matter what part of the human I take to track its movements like face or whole body ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is detecting a human face area in each frame and drawing a rectangle covering the area. I'm not an expert in face detection area but did auto caricature generating project using [ASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_shape_model). Analyzing color histogram is one of the ways to do it but I remember shape based approaches were working much better. Also, check out [AAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_appearance_model) as it is an improved model from [ASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_shape_model). If you google them, you should be able to find a lot of articles. BTW, if you need a quick way, I would recommend using [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection). It already has very nice and simple functions to detect multiple faces in one image and get those areas as rectangles.

Comment: what do you mean 'get those areas as rectangles' ? Do you mean to say straight line rectangles without the dotted thing in them ?

Comment: Drawing dotted lines is totally up to you. OpenCV gives you CvRect which contains position, width and height of rectangles. Please click the OpenCV link in my answer and see the example code.